# What are the most important security controls to implement when deploying BYOD in an organization?

Tags: network, banks, byod

In organizations like banks that have already many security controls. Will implementing BYOD (our organization employees will be able to use their own computers to access the organization when they decide to work remotely) in the company will require additional security controls? if so what are the most important security controls to implement when deploying BYOD in an organization?

Comment: I flagged this question as too broad. First, BYOD does not always mean the same thing in different companies. There are different ways to interpret and implement BYOD in practice which all have their unique security challenges. Second, pretty much all possible interpretations of BYOD have unique challenges, and which are more or less important depends on the unique circumstances and security requirements of the organization. So answering this question for the general case would require to account for too many variables.

Comment: But this question would be answerable if you would add more details about the BYOD policy your company is planning and what the security requirements of your company are.

Comment: Made some changes explaining what kind of BYOD I meant. You can edit the question if you think it will help to make it more clear.

Comment: You say "employees work remotely with their own devices". What does that mean? How do they communicate with the company network? What kind of applications are they using and how are they using it? How high is the protection level of the information they work with?

Comment: What would your employees be accessing?  Would it include confidential customer data?  Are there local laws and regulations that regulate the protection of the data they would be able to access?  What controls you implement are highly dependent upon the risks you want to mitigate.  If you are asking here for the purpose of coming up with a policy, I'd recommend instead you hire a security consultant to analyze your company's needs and work with you to come up with a policy - a bank especially has a lot of risk.

Comment: Please give me some time to put those details in the question.

Comment: Hi @Filopn - once you have edited your question accordingly, please flag for reopening. Having worked with banks for the last 20 years I have to say there is no one size fits all, so I am unsure if you will be able to edit this question into a form which is not too broad, but try and remove "most important" as that is different everywhere.